# Flutter Pass Objects from one page to other page

Tags: flutter

How to pass json Object from one page to another page in flutter ?

Just while routing i will able to pass parameters in routing path

but i need to pass some custom json object and display in other page ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass the object in the constructor

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (__) => new HomeScreen(myObject:object)));
```

...

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  var myObject;
  HomeScreen({
    this.myObject
  });
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text(widget.myObject.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: very nice explaineed

Comment: May I ask where the `widget` in `widget.myObject.toString()` come from?

Comment: @alimbaronia It's a standard way to reference variables from the `StatefulWidget`. Here's an official example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#widgets.StatefulWidget.2